# How do I display search results using a ajax request to pull php results using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

l I have managed to create a search engine which retrieves my results in my mysql database. I can view elements of this this data. However I was looking to display search results in the same style I have on my page titled news.php.

Search.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $search = $_POST['search'];
  $search = "%$search%";
  $articles = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE headline LIKE     :search");
  $articles->bindParam(':search', $search);
  $articles->execute(array(':search' => $search));

  if($articles -> rowCount() > 0) {
      while ($rows = $articles->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
           $headline = $rows['headline'];
           echo "headline: $headline<br>";
          }
  } else{
    echo "No Results";
  }
}
```

News.php

```
 $query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM articles');
 $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 for ($i=0; $i < count($results); $i++) { 
   echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 height-news">';
   echo '<p class="news-title">'.$results[$i]['headline'].'<br>'.'</p>';

   echo '<img class="news-img" src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode     ( $results[$i]['logo'] ).'"/>';
   echo '<p class="news-time">'.$results[$i]['date'].'<br>'.'</p>';
   echo nl2br('<p class="news-body">'.$results[$i]['text'].'<br>'.'</p>')     ;
     echo '</div>';
 }
```

Comment: And what's stopping you?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Too broad and unclear... Please take a look at the [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am trying to show all data in connection with the headline??

Answer (score 0):

You will need to post to the search.php file. Try something like this:

```
$('#yourSearhcButton").click(function(){
     $.post("link/to/Search.php", { search: search });
});
```

Read the docs -> https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/